# How to add onBackPressedCallback to fragment?

Tags: android

I've seen this mentioned in a couple of places but cant quite work out how to implement it as there are no example online, I'm wondering whether I've misinterpreted its meaning.

[the android developer link for addOnBackPressedCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity)

I was wondering whether this means I can add a callback inside my fragment to pick up the `onBackPressed()` before it hits the activity.

**In my fragment I've implemented**

```
implements OnBackPressedCallBack
```

**then implemented the method**

```
@Override
public boolean handleOnBackPressed() {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleOnBackPressed: hello");
    return true;
}
```

**But its not picking it up and going straight to main activity `onBackPressed()`.**

I read on further and saw that My fragment needed to extend from FragmentActivity

```
public class MainExampleFragment extends FragmentActivity implements View.OnClickListener, OnBackPressedCallback {
```

and instead of

```
appCompatActivity.getSuppportFragmentManager
```

to call

```
FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager
```

instead, but this throws and error in the Fragment.newInstance method when trying to set the bundle.

Has anyone info on doing this please thanks

Comment: Using event bus on back press

Answer (score 20):

As @Derek Zhu pointed out, it seems that if you override onBackPressed in your activity then the Fragment's onBackPressedCallback doesn't work. I found that if I wanted to also use it in the activity then I needed to use `onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback` there also.

Activity:

```
onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(
        this,
        object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Activity back pressed invoked")
                // Do custom work here    

                // if you want onBackPressed() to be called as normal afterwards
                if (isEnabled) {
                    isEnabled = false
                    requireActivity().onBackPressed()
                }
            }
        }
)
```

Fragment:

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(
        this,
        object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Fragment back pressed invoked")
                // Do custom work here    

                // if you want onBackPressed() to be called as normal afterwards
                if (isEnabled) {
                    isEnabled = false
                    requireActivity().onBackPressed()
                }
            }
        }
)
```

The result of the above is that Fragment back pressed will be invoked, then Activity back pressed.

Comment: Important note! This callback will not working if you override onBackPressed method of activity! I spent a lot of time before figure it out...

Answer (score 4):

This is what I did

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, onBackPressedCallback);
    }

    private final OnBackPressedCallback onBackPressedCallback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true /* Enabled by default */) {
        @Override
        public void handleOnBackPressed() {
            // Handle the back button event

            if (fieldsModified()) {
                // User made changes on EditText on the Fragment. Confirm exit to avoid loss of data

                AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                builder.setMessage(msg_confirm_close_form);
                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        closeFragment();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.btn_no, null);
                builder.show();
            }
            else {
                closeFragment();
            }
        }

        private void closeFragment() {
            // Disable to close fragment
            this.setEnabled(false);
            requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().onBackPressed();
        }
    };  
}
```

You must implement a callback in your Fragment to intercept the onBackPressed event throught a dispatcher from you activity.

Comment: requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().onBackPressed() applicatioin crashed when i write this line why ??

Comment: This approach worked well for me. @SunilChaudhary the activity this fragment is attached too extends `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity` - Maybe check what activity type you're extending and check you're using the latest version of the androidx appcompat dependency. I'm using `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha02`

Answer (score 2):

if anybody dont know i am update OnBackPressedCallBack for both fragment and AppCompacTActivity and I have Nested Fragment here

in Fragment

```
public class MessageFragment extends Fragment  {

public MessageFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // This callback will only be called when MyFragment is at least Started.
    OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true ) {
        @Override
        public void handleOnBackPressed() {
            // Handle the back button event
            FragmentManager fm= getFragmentManager();
            if (fm != null) {
                if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                    fm.popBackStack();
                    Log.e( "backpress Frag","back" );

                }

                List<Fragment> fragList = fm.getFragments();
                if (fragList != null && fragList.size() > 0) {
                    for (Fragment frag : fragList) {
                        if (frag == null) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (frag.isVisible()) {
                          Log.e( "backpress Frag","Visible" );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    };
    requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root=inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_listning, container, false );

    return root;
}
```

and you in MainActivity remove your OnBackpressed() method and add this new Method

```
OnBackPressedCallback onBackPressedCallback = new OnBackPressedCallback( true ) {
    boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
    @Override
    public void handleOnBackPressed() {

        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            ActivityCompat.finishAffinity( FirstActivity.this );
            Log.e( "Click", "double back" );
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(FirstActivity.this,getStrin(R.string.exitapp),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed( new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
            }
        }, 2000);


    }
};

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_first );
    //getting bottom navigation view and attaching the listener


    getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback( this, onBackPressedCallback );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> AppCompatActivity extends FragmentActivity extends
>   ComponentActivity(androidx.fragment.app.ComponentActivity) extends
>   (androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity)

so addOnBackPressedCallback should work for AppCompatActivity too

Comment: I had the exact same issue, as it turns out it's because I overrided onBackPressed() in the activity and super method is not called in some situation, therefore fragment is not receiving the dispatched event call

Comment: Keep in mind that `OnBackPressedCallback` was introduced in latest version of AppCompat which is `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01` as of today

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Approach**

It is now very easy to add backpress handler to any fragment with
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedDispatcher

---

**Deprecated Approach: DO NOT USE**

You can't directly handle `onBackpressed` inside a fragment.

What you can do instead is pass the `onBackPressed` event to the current displayed fragment through some way.

One basic way is to create an interface like so:

```
interface BackHandler {
    handleBackPressed(): Boolean
}
```

then implementing this on your fragment like so:

```
class YourFragment : Fragment(), BackHandler {
    ...
    override handleBackPressed(): Boolean {
        // do Your thing here
    }
    ...
}
```

On your Activity do this on `onBackPressed`:

```
class YourActivity: Activity() {
    ...
    override onBackPressed() {
        val currentFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(yourviewid)
        if (currentFragment is BackHandler) {
            (currentFragment as BackHandler).handleBackPressed()
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

That is just one way to do it. Yo could also use something like an `EventBus` or some other implementation. The key point is that Android doesn't provide this out of the box for fragments.

Comment: this may be a method too, using interface. But this is old now and doing something that is as simple as just a Callback on backButtonPress, it is much more work to do. BTW, you are wrong in the statement "You can't directly handle onBackpressed inside a fragment".

You are able to add the OnBackPressed but in a different manner. Refer to 

https://proandroiddev.com/backpress-handling-in-android-fragments-the-old-and-the-new-method-c41d775fb776

Comment: This is a deprecated approach now.. I didn't even remember I have this here. This answer was posted years before the new approach is available. You could simply ignore this. I'll update my answer when I got some time.

Answer (score -1):

Kotlin:

```
     val mOnBackPressedCallback= object : OnBackPressedCallback(active) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            if (active) {
                // Do something
            } else {
                // call onBackPressed() as normal afterwards
                remove()
                requireActivity().onBackPressed()
            }
        }
    }
```

Add Callback to dispatcher:
`requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner, mOnBackPressedCallback)`