# Should calls to onBackPressed() be treated differently from API 33?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack, androidx

I am using `onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback()` to handle back press.
I am not using override of `onBackPressed()` to handle back press.
However, I do call `onBackPressed()` when following the back press I want it to conditionally do the default back.

What worries me is a statement in [Androd's documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back#onbackpressed) saying the following:
*`In Android 12 (API level 32) and lower, onBackPressed is always called, regardless of any registered instances of OnBackPressedCallback.`*

I wonder if I should do anything different for API 32 and less.

I did not observe any different behavior when running on API 32 vs API 33 by testing and by debugging. On both I see in `ComponentActivity`

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        getOnBackPressedDispatcher().onBackPressed();
  }
```

and in `OnBackPressedDispatcher`

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        Iterator<OnBackPressedCallback> iterator =
                mOnBackPressedCallbacks.descendingIterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            OnBackPressedCallback callback = iterator.next();
            if (callback.isEnabled()) {
                callback.handleOnBackPressed();
                return;
            }
        }
        if (mFallbackOnBackPressed != null) {
            mFallbackOnBackPressed.run();
        }
    }
```

(and it does not look like debugger showing wrong source).

So I do not understand what they meant by this comment. I think maybe it is related to the compilation SDK, not to the running Android version. Or maybe this was a mistake relating the comment to the android SDK, instead of `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` library version.

I am aware also of the deprecation of `onBackPressed` in `ComponentActivity` and the possibility to call the one of `OnBackPressedDispatcher` directly. But this does not help me with understating the situation.

Comment: You shouldn't ever be manually calling `onBackPressed` anyways. If you have an Up button in your UI, etc. it should be talking directly to the state it wants to change. Can you explain your use case for calling it in the first place?

Comment: I am calling it in OnBackPressedCallback::handleOnBackPressed() to perfrom the default back on some condition. Before the call I set isEnabled = false.

Comment: That's entirely the wrong thing to do and exactly what breaks the [Predictive Back Gesture](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/custom-back/predictive-back-gesture). I'd suggest asking another question with your code asking how you should instead write it to avoid doing that. Feel free to include a link here.

Comment: There are many questions about it already and I did not see any other suggestion. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55074497/how-to-add-onbackpressedcallback-to-fragment?rq=4 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73212710/android-custom-onbackpressed-to-onbackpressedcallback

Comment: In my code the decision if to do the default or not depends on some elapsed time along with other conditions about whether some things were done or not.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I thought you would give an answer there. I appreciate your answers so far, however, I am just left with the statement that "That's entirely the wrong thing to do". I think Google should have added a function to OnBackPressedCallback like "isExpectedToHandleBack()" and call it whenever the system needs to know the momentary answer. But I guess Google had some other idea, which I currently do not know what it is despite reading the docs and watching the videos.

Comment: The whole point of the ahead of time model for handling system back, if you had really watched the [video linked in the guide](https://youtu.be/Elpqr5xpLxQ), is to enable and disable your callback whenever your state changes so that you only get a callback when you can handle back - you never do any conditional checking just in time.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I did watch it earlier. What I do not understand is what Google expects from the software design. Letting the details that are spread around the app to know they should call some function to update the enable state of the back callback? That is bug prone, breaks encapsulation, messy, and against any reasonable software design. I still hope Google does have some idea of what the code design should look like. Currently from what I see there should have been a "isExpectedToHandleBack()" as I mentioned, to override by the app and be called by the system.